# How to pass match options to a within block in capybara 2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

After updating capybara to 2.1, It is throwing Ambiguous error

```
Capybara::Ambiguous:
   Ambiguous match, found 2 elements matching css "div.alert"
```

and after reading some [articles and the log here](http://www.elabs.se/blog/60-introducing-capybara-2-1). You can get the default behaviour from 1.0x by passing `:match => :prefer_exact`

This can be easily done for something like `fill`, like this

```
fill ("Password", :match => :prefer_exact'
```

but how do you do it for a `within` block like this

```
within 'div.alert' do
  page.should have_content(text)
end
```

I tried doing this, but it throws an error

```
within ('div.alert', :match => :prefer_exact) do
  page.should have_content(text)
end
```

any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: I find in general I can make the UI itself easier to traverse for CSS. Maybe give important DIVs IDs that you can tap in to, and use that in Capybara - it also organizes your page more. So hopefully then you can do: `within "#messages.alert"` or `within "#popup-container.alert"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't know the order and have no way to select it by CSS, you can try

```
page.should have_selector('.alert', text: 'foo bar')
```

There is no need for `within`, which is designed for larger divs with complex content.

Comment: actually i did something similar. I remove `within` and did     `page.should have_content(text)` but your is more concise